# Set theory problem with preimages

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if $f : X\to Y,$ $A\subseteq X,$ $B \subseteq Y,$ then $f (f^{-1} (B)) = B \cap f(X)$ and $f(A) \cap B = f(A \cap f^{-1} (B)).$

I'm having trouble with this problem. Does anybody have ideas how to approach this?

Comment: What is the $x$ that shows up just before the "and" in the problem statement?

Comment: I don't understand the first line, it reads: “$f$ mapsto if $x$ then $A$ is a subset of $B$."  Enlighten me, please.

Comment: I edited your post. Could you check that it is what you intended?

Comment: What does it mean "set theory problem with originals"? Clearly English is not your native tongue, but have you used Google Translate for the title? If so, perhaps write in a comment the term in the original language, so it can be translated by someone.

Comment: @Asaf In some languages (including Dutch), variants on "original" are sometimes used for "preimage". I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yes, that was my guess. In Hebrew the words are closely related as well, so I am not surprised by this fact. I didn't want to assume anything, and preferred that the OP writes the native term in the original language.

Answer (score 1):

I explain the first one, the second one going the same way.

$f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B\cap f(X)$: let $x \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. Then $x = f(c)$ with $c\in f^{-1}(B)$, by definition of being in the image of something. By the definition of preimage, one has that $f(c) \in B$, hence $x\in B$. On the other hand, $c\in X$ so $f(c) \in f(X)$ and $x\in f(X)$, from which we conclude that $x \in B\cap f(X)$, i.e $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B\cap f(X)$.

$ B\cap f(X)\subseteq f(f^{-1}(B)) $: let $y \in B\cap f(X)$. Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Since $y\in B$, $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, hence $y = f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(B))$, as required.